# Histograms with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count, histogram

I have two entity types in a one-to-many association:

`A --1:*--> B`

I would like to obtain a histogram of counts of `b` per each `a` in ActiveRecord.
Something like:

```
A.id   | count(B)
1      | 20
2      | 32
3      | 332
4      | 0
```

`[ {:id=>1, :count=>20},{:id=>2,:count=>32}, ... ]`

I could do it directly in mySql but I was wondering the proper way of doing it on ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's always going to be a bit of a mix and match of AR and SQL.

Let's say you want to count comments for each post. The following code:

```
Post.joins(:comments).group("posts.id").count("comments.id")
```

will produce something like:

```
{2=>304, 3=>329, 4=>46, 6=>342}
```

where the hash keys are the post ids. Notice, however, that because of the inner join enforced by `joins` you will only get posts with existing comments. But, just like in your example, it makes sense to also list post ids that have *zero* comments.

You might then think to `include`, rather than joining comments:

```
Post.includes(:comments).group("posts.id").count("comments.id")
```

But that won't work. For reasons I am not completely sure about, the `includes` is ignored by AR, which results in and a database error.

In the end, I resorted to the following much more explicit and sql-ish query:

```
Post.select("posts.id, COUNT(comments.id) AS comm_count")
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON posts.id=comments.post_id")
    .group("posts.id")
```

This will return an array of actual Post models (not just `:id => count` hashes) with the added attribute `comm_count`, which is what you need.

Of course you may add other post attributes to the `select`, such as the title, the content, etc.